# Using jquery.slideToggle() with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

So basically I am looking to create a custom binding so that when the user clicks on a hide/show button I want to toggle the display of the list element underneath it.

At the moment I can get it to partially work, basically if I start with the elements hidden (this.showGalaxys set to false) then click on the hide/show they appear. But the opposite does not occur, that is I cannot hide the now visible list elements.

Ignore the elements after the galaxys section as they will use the same implementation as the galaxy section.

Also keep in mind that I am binding data to these objects earlier in the HTML, that is all working correctly, the only issue is my logic for toggling display of elements.

Here is the relevant section of my HTML Markup:

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3YkZ/7/)

```
<h2>Results</h2>
<br/>

<div data-bind="foreach: universes">

    <strong style="color: tomato">Universe: </strong><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <br/><br/>

    <div style="padding-left: 20px">

        <strong style="color: teal; padding-right: 20px">Galaxys</strong><button data-bind="click: toggleGalaxys">Show/Hide</button>
        <ul data-bind="fadeVisible: displayGalaxys">

            <div data-bind="foreach: galaxys">

                <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
                <div style="padding-left: 20px">

                    <strong style="color: sandybrown; padding-right: 20px">Star System</strong><button data-bind="fadeVisible: showStarSystems">Show/Hide</button>
                    <ul id="starSystemsList">

                        <div data-bind="foreach: starSystems">

                            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
                            <div style="padding-left: 20px">

                                <strong style="color: purple; padding-right: 20px">Planets</strong>
                                <ul>
                                    <div data-bind="foreach: planets">

                                        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>

                                    </div>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript code being used:

```
    function UniverseViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.universes = ko.observableArray();

    self.addUniverse = function() {
        self.universes.push(new Universe(""));
    };
}

function Universe(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.galaxys = ko.observableArray();

    this.addGalaxy = function() {
        this.galaxys.push(new Galaxy(""));
    };

    this.displayGalaxys = ko.observable(false);

    this.toggleGalaxys = function () {
        this.displayGalaxys = !this.displayGalaxys;
    };
}

function Galaxy(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.starSystems = ko.observableArray();

    this.addStarSystem = function() {
        this.starSystems.push(new StarSystem(""));
    };

    this.showStarSystems = ko.observable(false);

}

function StarSystem(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.planets = ko.observableArray();

    this.addPlanet = function() {
        this.planets.push(new Planet(""));
    };

    this.removePlanet = function(planet) {
        this.planets.remove(planet);
    };

    this.showPlanets = ko.observable(false);
}

function Planet(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new UniverseViewModel());
```

Comment: I created this jsFiddle but neither hide nor show (false or true) are working: http://jsfiddle.net/VqGew/

Comment: sorry I had recently changed my code, neither do work at this stage, if I instead do the following it works as above:

<strong style="color: teal; padding-right: 20px">Galaxys</strong><button data-bind="click: displayGalaxys">Show/Hide</button>
                        <ul data-bind="fadeVisible: displayGalaxys">

Comment: please add a jsFiddle with "working code" i'll happily get you up and running.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W3YkZ/7/ theres the link, it doesn't work in that environment for some reason however.

Comment: answer posted, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to solving this can be found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html), which describes that

> **data-bind="fadeVisible: variable":** requires the variable to be an observable that is true or false.  You then on your button click change the variable to the opposite...

*Enjoy the below solution:*

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3YkZ/9/)

**HTML:**

```
<div style="padding-left: 80px">
     <h2>Input</h2>

    <br/>
    <!-- table for input of names -->
    <button data-bind="click: addUniverse">Add New Universe</button>
    <div data-bind="foreach: universes" style="padding-left: 50px">
        <input data-bind="value: name" />
        <br/>
        <button data-bind="click: addGalaxy">Add Galaxies</button>
        <br/>
        <div data-bind="foreach: galaxys" style="padding-left: 50px">
            <input data-bind="value: name" />
            <br/>
            <button data-bind="click: addStarSystem">Add Star System</button>
            <br/>
            <div data-bind="foreach: starSystems" style="padding-left: 50px">
                <input data-bind="value: name" />
                <br/>
                <button data-bind="click: addPlanet">Add Planet</button>
                <br/>
                <div data-bind="foreach: planets" style="padding-left: 50px">
                    <input data-bind="value: name" />
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
     <h2>Results</h2>

    <br/>
    <div data-bind="foreach: universes"> <strong style="color: tomato">Universe: </strong><span data-bind="text: name"></span>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div style="padding-left: 20px"> <strong style="color: teal; padding-right: 20px">Galaxys</strong>

            <button data-bind="click: toggleGalaxys">Show/Hide</button>
            <ul data-bind="fadeVisible: displayGalaxys">
                <div data-bind="foreach: galaxys">
                    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
                    <div style="padding-left: 20px"> <strong style="color: sandybrown; padding-right: 20px">Star System</strong>

                        <button data-bind="click: toggleStarSystems">Show/Hide</button>
                        <ul data-bind="fadeVisible: showStarSystems">
                            <div data-bind="foreach: starSystems">
                                <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
                                <div style="padding-left: 20px"> <strong style="color: purple; padding-right: 20px">Planets</strong>

                                    <button data-bind="click: toggleShowPlanets">Show/Hide</button>
                                    <ul data-bind="fadeVisible: showPlanets">
                                        <div data-bind="foreach: planets">
                                            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function UniverseViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.universes = ko.observableArray();

    self.addUniverse = function () {
        self.universes.push(new Universe(""));
    };
}

function Universe(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.galaxys = ko.observableArray();

    this.addGalaxy = function () {
        this.galaxys.push(new Galaxy(""));
    };

    this.displayGalaxys = ko.observable(false);

    this.toggleGalaxys = function () {
        this.displayGalaxys(!this.displayGalaxys());
    };
}

function Galaxy(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.starSystems = ko.observableArray();

    this.addStarSystem = function () {
        this.starSystems.push(new StarSystem(""));
    };

    this.showStarSystems = ko.observable(false);

    this.toggleStarSystems = function () {
        this.showStarSystems(!this.showStarSystems());
    };
}

function StarSystem(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.planets = ko.observableArray();

    this.addPlanet = function () {
        this.planets.push(new Planet(""));
    };

    this.removePlanet = function (planet) {
        this.planets.remove(planet);
    };

    this.showPlanets = ko.observable(false);

    this.toggleShowPlanets = function () {
        this.showPlanets(!this.showPlanets());
    };
}

function Planet(name) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new UniverseViewModel());
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
}
header, footer, hgroup, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
}
.clear-fix:after {
    content:".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 .content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}
#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
.main-content {
    background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.featured + .main-content {
    background: url("../Images/heroAccent.png") no-repeat;
}
header .content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
}
/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 .site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}
.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 #login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
#login a {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#login a.username {
    background: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#login ul {
    margin: 0;
}
#login li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul#menu li a {
    background: none;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* featured */
 .featured {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.featured .content-wrapper {
    background-color: #7ac0da;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    color: #3e5667;
    padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
}
.featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
    color: #fff;
}
.featured p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
/* page titles */
 hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}
hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
/* features */
 section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* ordered list */
 ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ol.round li {
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding-left: 45px;
}
ol.round li.zero {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.one {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.two {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.three {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.four {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.five {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.six {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.seven {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.eight {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
}
ol.round li.nine {
    background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
}
/* content */
 article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}
aside ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
aside ul li {
    background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
}
.label {
    font-weight: 700;
}
/* login page */
 #loginForm {
    border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}
#loginForm .validation-error {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
#socialLoginForm h2 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
fieldset.open-auth-providers {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
fieldset.open-auth-providers button {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
/* contact */
 .contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}
.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}
/* forms */
 fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
fieldset legend {
    display: none;
}
fieldset ol {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
fieldset ol li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
label.checkbox {
    display: inline;
}
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 500px;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: transparent;
    border: inherit;
    width: auto;
}
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
}
td input[type="submit"], td input[type="button"], td button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
/* info and errors */
 .message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}
.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}
.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}
/* styles for validation helpers */
 .field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}
input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}
input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}
.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}
th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
th a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
}
th a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
th.asc a, th.desc a {
    margin-right: .75em;
}
th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0em;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
th.asc a:after {
    content:'▲';
}
th.desc a:after {
    content:'▼';
}
td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 0 none;
}
tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}
/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left, header .float-right {
        float: none;
    }
    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #login ul {
        margin: 5px 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #login a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #login a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }
    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul#menu li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-content, .featured + .main-content {
        background-position: 10px 0;
    }
    .content-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    .featured .content-wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    /* page content */
    article, aside {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* ordered list */
    ol.round {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    ol.round li {
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin: 25px 0;
    }
    ol.round li.zero, ol.round li.one, ol.round li.two, ol.round li.three, ol.round li.four, ol.round li.five, ol.round li.six, ol.round li.seven, ol.round li.eight, ol.round li.nine {
        background: none;
    }
    /* features */
    section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
    }
    section.feature img {
        color: #999;
        content: attr(alt);
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }
    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left, footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }
    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    footer p {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
/* END: Mobile Styles */
```